# Swapping ERC20 tokens on MyEtherWallet

Tags: erc-20, myetherwallet, swaps

I just found out about the token swapping function of MyEtherWallet: https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/swap/swapping-via-kyber-bity-changelly/

Now, let's say I have a lot of ERC20 tokens that I want to swap for ETH. Is there an upper limit to the amount from which I can swap? If someone obtained a massive stash of ERC20 tokens (for example, tokens that are worth billions in total), can he or she swap them directly for ETH?

EDIT: I'm asking this question because I've heard that a lot of scam token developers assign a lot of their newly created tokens for themselves, and then dump them on the market. Sometimes, the dev can dump billions or trillions of these scam tokens for profit. I'm wondering if these people can just insta-dump trillions of tokens by simply swapping them on MyEtherWallet, or is there an upper limit to the amount which they can swap?

Answer (score 0):

Money does not appear from the thin air. In a swap, there is always a buyer who will buy your tokens.

The available price point depends on the underlying liquidity. It might be easy to sell a small amount of tokens, but any large amount of tokens would probably move the price down, as there are not enough buyers for your token.